# Vb.net interface with power point

Tags: vb.net

Hi i tried the following simple code, but it has error of 
Object variable or With block variable not set.

```
   Module Module1

    Sub main()

    Dim ppt As Presentation = Nothing

    ppt.LoadFromFile("C:\Users\310238479\Desktop\test.pptx")
    End Module 
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I seems that you are not using vb.net only, but spire.presentation.

As the commands are correct, please verify, that you try to access an existing file and you have sufficient rights ...